# Is there a way to remove the pagination from an ActiveRelation object?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

Let's say we have `@posts = Post.published.per(10).page(params[:page])` somewhere in our controller. Later on we need to update all published posts (`Post.published`).

**How should one remove the pagination?**

`@posts.limit(false).offset(false)` seems to do the trick but I think there should be some other way, a more high-level way (something like `@posts.without_pagination`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the `page` method is provided by kaminari, I do not sure if kaminari provide also something like `without_pagination`.

But if you like, you could always do this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.without_pagination
    self.limit(false).offset(false)
  end
end
```

or you could extract the method out to a module and include the module into ActiveRecord::Base so that every model has the method.

### Edited

Thank you tfwright for pointing out. Could use `.except(:limit, :offset)` which should be much better for later comers.

```
@posts = Post.publised.per(10).page(params[:page])
@posts = @posts.except(:limit, :offset)
```

Comment: Kaminari now provides a method to unscope pagination: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#unscoping. I'm not sure if it currently behaves any differently, but it might be more future proof to use it rather than overriding the AR options directly.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are using WillPaginate on arrays. Would be good to have a solution that works for both Relations and Arrays